# I have gitlab repository, under one repository I have many projects. Now I want to intergrate gitlab with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, webhooks, continuous-deployment

I have gitlab repository, under one repository I have many projects. Now I want to intergrate gitlab with Jenkins . So normllay when ever a commit happen in git repo the solution file in the repository should build.
But in my case if I integrate with Jenkins I have many solutions files in same repository.so I want to trigger only the solution file which is related to the commited file.

Is their any way by using webhook (or any way ) to know what folder of the repository is modified ? So that I can run related solution file based on the path

Folder structure:
Project1/project1.sln and dependent files 
Project2/project2.sln and dependent files

Thanks in advance.and also please guide for githab webhook configuration to integrate with Jenkins .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GitLab Webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) can be created in the GitLab Web-Interface. The modified files are listed in the [body of the Push-Message](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#push-events).

**Solution with the Git Plugin**

1. Create a Freestyle Job for one solution file e.g. `Project1`
2. Go to `Build Trigges`
3. Select `Poll SCM`.
4. Leave `Schedule` empty
5. Go to `Source-Code-Management`
6. Select `Git`
7. Configure Repository URL and Credentials
8. Enter Branch e.g. `refs/heads/master`
9. Select Repository Browser `(AUTO)`
10. At Additional Behaviours press `Add` Button the bottom
11. Select `Polling ignores commits in certain Paths`
12. Fill `Included Regions` with the path to the project folder e.g. `^Project1/*.`. That means it will only trigger the build if changes in that folder or it's subfolders are detected.
13. Go to `Post-Build Actions` at the bottom of the job configuration and press `Add` Button
14. Select `Clean Workspace after Build`
15. Add `Patterns for files to be deleted` press `Add` Button
16. Select `Exclude`
17. Enter `**/.git/*`
18. Select Checkbox `Apply pattern also on directories`

When GitLab sends a Push Message, Jenkins will trigger SCM polling of this job. It will verify if there are changes in the related folder. Build will start if this is the case.

You can check the git polling protocol at /job//scmPollLog/

**Solution with the GitLab Plugin**

The [Jenkins GitLab Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#webhook-url) would also be a solution.

Comment: Hi @matthias ,thanks for response.where does the push message stored in Jenkins ?

Comment: Hi, I made some fiddling myself and made it work without the gitlab plugin. This way you do not need to parse the body of the push messages. I edited my original answer. Let me know if there are more Questions.

Comment: Is it mandatory to delete workspace when the build is done ? Will it delete old job logs too ??

Comment: It's optional to delete it. But if you delete it, it's mandatory to exclude the .git folder. otherwise the scm polling won't work. It needs a reference.

Comment: I followed your steps" Solution with the Git Plugin", but the job is not triggered. Do i need to add webhook here ? By any chance it is due to firewall ? We  access gitlab only from our network.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You also need to configure the Webhook in the GitLab WebInterface. See the first sentence of my post. You can also verify your jenkins configuration by calling the POST request manually e.g. `curl http://yourserver/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>`

Comment: Hi Matthias, I am confused, Let me explain what and all i did. a) I add api token of my gitlab and connection is success. b) I have added repo details in SCM. c) now in gitlab i have added webhook ( getting error). Where should i add the URL which you provided ??

Comment: If your machine or jenkins itself are on Unix you can just enter the curl command in console.

Comment: okay thanks Matthias, Now due to firewall issues, we are not using webhook. Thanks for all your support.It is really helpful for me.